# Call to a member function save() on null Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Пытаюсь сделать добавление данных в бд из формы , выдает такую ошибку , если я правильно понял - то из-за отсутствия одного из значений ,но они вроде есть .Ошибка Call to a member function save() on null  в \controllers\SiteController.php  строка   if($model -> save()){

SiteController

```
public function actionForm()
      {
          $form = new BriefForm();
  
          
  
          $form->site_name = 'Sa';
          $form->email = 'mail@s.com';
          $form->phone = '09723232';
          $form->user_FIO = 'YAV';
          $form->additional_info= 'vaiasasaco';
          $form->domain_name = "ssss";
          
          
  
          
         
  
          if($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
              if($model -> save()){
                  Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'data acceepted');
                  return $this->refresh();
  
              }else{
                  Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error' , 'failed');
              }
              
          }
  
          $this->view->title = 'All posts';
          return $this->render('test', compact('model'));
          
  
      }
```

models/BriefForm

```
<?php 
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord; 




class BriefForm extends  ActiveRecord
{
     public $site_name;
    //  public $operation_kind_new;
    //  public $operation_kind_old;
    
     public $user_FIO;
     public $email;
     public $phone;
     public $additional_info;
     public $domain_name;
    //  public $domain_items = [];
        

    // // ];
    //  public $old_site_defect_items = [];



    public static function tableName(){
        return 'brief_form';
    }
    




    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['site_name','operation_kind','user_FIO','email','phone', 'domain_name'], 'required'],
            ['email' , 'email' , 'message'=> 'Некорректный email' ],

        ];
    }
```

views/form

```
<?php $f= ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'site_name')->label('Название вашего сайта'); ?>
                  <h3 class="text-center">Что нужно сделать</h3>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3 class="text-center">Создать новый</h3>  
                      <?=$f->field($form , 'domain_name')->label('Домен сайта'); ?>
                      
                      
                      
          
          
                  </div>
          
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h3 class="text-center">Обновить старый</h3>  
                      <?=$f->field($form , 'domain_name')->label('Домен сайта'); ?>
                      
                        <?=$f->field($form , 'additional_info')->label('Дополнительные сведения'); ?>
                     
                  </div>
          
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'user_FIO')->label('Ваше ФИО'); ?>
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'email')->label('Ваша почта'); ?>
                  <?=$f->field($form , 'phone')->label('Ваш номер телефона'); ?>
                  
                  <?= Html::submitButton('Вперед'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: `$model -> save()` - откуда $model? Мб `$form->save()`?

Comment: `Call to a member function save() on null` - ошибка говорит, что вы вызываете функцию у null. А не из-за отсутствия одного из значений

Comment: Вы чертовски правы , уже целый день ковыряюсь в форме этой . Поменял значения и еще в return $this->render('form', compact('form'));  поменял .Теперь ловлю другие ошибки  .Можете еще подсказать выводило ошибку General error: 1364 Field 'phone' doesn't have a default value      -  я в БД поставил параметр "По умолчанию " - "Null"  .Теперь после отправки формы в бд появляются NULL'ы ,как это исправить можно ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O_o**
Привет, немного зарефакторил, посмотри, разберись, думаю все станет ясно)))

**SiteController**

```js
    public function actionForm()
    {
        $model = new BriefForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->refresh();
        }

        return $this->render('form', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

**BriefForm**

```js
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class BriefForm extends ActiveRecord
{
    // Все аттрибуты по таблице создаются в модели автоматически, объявляя их, ты их переопреопределяешь, из-за этого
    // у тебя и null по всем полям, так делать НЕЛЬЗЯ!!!

    // public $user_FIO;
    // public $email;
    // public $phone;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function tableName(): string
    {
        return 'brief_form';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            [['site_name', 'operation_kind', 'user_FIO', 'email', 'phone', 'domain_name'], 'required'],
            [['email'], 'email', 'message' => 'Некорректный email'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_FIO' => Yii::t('app', 'Ваше ФИО'),
            'email'    => Yii::t('app', 'Ваша почта'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes): void
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'data acceepted');
    }
}
```

**View**

```js
<?php

use app\models\BriefForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/** @var $model BriefForm */
/** @var $this View */

$this->title = 'All posts';
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">

            <?= $form->field($model, 'site_name') ?>

            <h3 class="text-center"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Что нужно сделать') ?></h3>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="text-center"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Создать новый') ?></h3>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'domain_name') ?>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="text-center"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Обновить старый') ?></h3>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'additional_info') ?>

            </div>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'user_FIO') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'phone') ?>

            <?= Html::submitButton('Вперед') ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Удачи, фреймворк клевый на самом деле)))))

Comment: Ого , большое спасибо за пример  , обязательно разберусь, на первый взгляд все понятно  , вот что значит хороший код